# naive bayes classifier: does the size of corpus for each category have to be the same?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, naivebayes

I am building a Naive Bayes classifier for two categories, pos and neg. I want the classifier to classify a sentence as pos if it contains certain words and as neg if it doesn't contain those words.

My corpus for pos are 518 sentences that contain those words. My question: How big does the corpus for neg have to be?

In the movie_reviews corpus of NLTK, both categories contain the same amount of text files. However, that classifier also learns the negative words, doesn't it? I really only care that the classifier recognizes certain words belongig to the pos category, I don't care about the words in the neg category.

So, is it important that both corpora contain 518 text files?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary for the two categories to have the same size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have a source for this somewhere? Or how do you know this for sure?